# Is “tapping therapy” effective for the treatment of psychological trauma in children?

Tags: medical-science

On BBC Radio 4 just now (“Woman’s Hour”, 26 Dec 2019), something called “tapping therapy” was mentioned for the treatment of psychological trauma in children.

I’ve looked it up and found this [2010 article in The Telegraph](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/lifestyle/wellbeing/7220734/Tapping-therapy-curing-physical-and-mental-problems.html):

> Tapping therapy: curing physical and mental problems
>
> Beverley Turner tries out 'tapping', a technique designed to cure physical and mental problems by tapping on the body's invisible energy pathways.
>
> ... based on the EFT therapy developed by American, Gary Craig in 1997. Craig had studied Dr. Callaghan's Thought Field Therapy in the 1980s, an evolution of John Diamond's Kinesiology, both of which were rooted in ancient Eastern "meridian energy" theories of acupuncture and Shiatsu, codified since at least 1000BC.
>
> These therapies claimed that our bodies contain invisible energy pathways – meridians – and identified hundreds of acupoints at junctions along these interconnecting highways. They can be disrupted by life's vicissitudes; in extreme cases, resulting in not only mental but also physical problems.
> EFT works by a person tapping on just nine of these acupoints, while speaking aloud.

Is “tapping therapy” effective for the treatment of psychological trauma in children?